# Get last known record per month in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Account balance collection, that shows the account balance of a customer at a given day:

```
+---------------+---------+------------+
|  customer_id  |  value  | timestamp  |
+---------------+---------+------------+
| 1             |  -500   | 2019-10-12 |
| 1             |  -300   | 2019-10-11 |
| 1             |  -200   | 2019-10-10 |
| 1             |  0      | 2019-10-09 |
| 2             |  200    | 2019-09-10 |
| 1             |  600    | 2019-09-02 |
+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Notice, that customer #2 had no updates to his account balance in October.

I want to get the last account balance per customer per month. If there has been no account balance update for a customer in a given month, the last known account balance should be transferred to the current month. The result should look like that:

```
+---------------+---------+------------+
|  customer_id  |  value  | timestamp  |
+---------------+---------+------------+
| 1             |  -500   | 2019-10-12 |
| 2             |  200    | 2019-10-10 |
| 2             |  200    | 2019-09-10 |
| 1             |  600    | 2019-09-02 |
+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Since the account balance of customer #2 was not updated in October but in September, we create a copy of the row from September changing the date to October. Any ideas how to achieve this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH customers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM `project.dataset.table`
), months AS (
  SELECT month FROM (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC(MIN(timestamp), MONTH) min_month, DATE_TRUNC(MAX(timestamp), MONTH) max_month
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_month, max_month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
)
SELECT customer_id, 
  IFNULL(value, LEAD(value) OVER(win)) value,  
  IFNULL(timestamp, DATE_ADD(LEAD(timestamp) OVER(win), INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(month, LEAD(month) OVER(win), MONTH) MONTH)) timestamp  
FROM months, customers
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(timestamp, MONTH) month, customer_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value, timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* 
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY month, customer_id
) USING(month, customer_id)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month DESC)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - as it is in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 customer_id, -500 value, DATE '2019-10-12' timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, -300, '2019-10-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, -200, '2019-10-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 200, '2019-09-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 100, '2019-08-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 50, '2019-07-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 600, '2019-09-02' 
), customers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM `project.dataset.table`
), months AS (
  SELECT month FROM (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC(MIN(timestamp), MONTH) min_month, DATE_TRUNC(MAX(timestamp), MONTH) max_month
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_month, max_month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
)
SELECT customer_id, 
  IFNULL(value, LEAD(value) OVER(win)) value,  
  IFNULL(timestamp, DATE_ADD(LEAD(timestamp) OVER(win), INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(month, LEAD(month) OVER(win), MONTH) MONTH)) timestamp  
FROM months, customers
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(timestamp, MONTH) month, customer_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value, timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* 
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY month, customer_id
) USING(month, customer_id)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month DESC)
-- ORDER BY month DESC, customer_id
```

result is

```
Row customer_id value   timestamp    
1   1           -500    2019-10-12   
2   2           200     2019-10-10   
3   1           600     2019-09-02   
4   2           200     2019-09-10   
5   1           null    null     
6   2           100     2019-08-11   
7   1           null    null     
8   2           50      2019-07-12
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! The query works almost. Check out your query with modified sample data: https://gist.github.com/artjomzab/c471b9aff7142bf8d0c73d2e4b880c8d The problem is, that it returns 600 for 2019-07-02, but this value was recorded at 2019-09-02

Answer (score 1):

The following query should mostly answer your question by creating a 'month-end' record for each customer for every month and getting the most recent balance:

```
with 

-- Generate a set of months
month_begins as (
  select dt from unnest(generate_date_array('2019-01-01','2019-12-01', interval 1 month)) dt
),

-- Get the month ends
month_ends as (
  select date_sub(date_add(dt, interval 1 month), interval 1 day) as month_end_date from month_begins
),

--  Cross Join and group so we get 1 customer record for every month to account for 
--  situations where customer doesn't change balance in a month
user_month_ends as (
  select
    customer_id,
    month_end_date
  from `project.dataset.table`
  cross join month_ends
  group by 1,2
),

--  Fan out so for each month end, you get all balances prior to month end for each customer
values_prior_to_month_end as (
  select
    customer_id,
    value,
    timestamp,
    month_end_date
  from `project.dataset.table`
  inner join user_month_ends using(customer_id)
  where timestamp <= month_end_date
),

-- Order by most recent balance before month end, even if it was more than 1+ months ago
ordered as (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by customer_id, month_end_date order by timestamp desc) as my_row
  from values_prior_to_month_end
),

-- Finally, select only the most recent record for each customer per month
final as (
  select
    * except(my_row)
  from ordered
  where my_row = 1
)
select * from final
order by customer_id, month_end_date desc
```

A few caveats:

1. I did not order results to match your desired result set, and I also kept a month-end date to illustrate the concept.  You can easily change the  ordering and exclude unneeded fields.
2. In the `month_begins` CTE, I set a range of months into the future, so your result set will contain the most recent balance of 'future months'.  To make this a bit prettier, consider changing `'2019-12-01'` to 'current_date()' and your query will always return to the end of the current month.
3. Your `timestamp` field looks to be dates, so I used date logic, but you should be able to apply the same principles to use timestamp logic if your underlying fields are actual timestamps.
4. In your result set, I'm not sure why your 2nd row (customer 2) would have a timestamp of '2019-10-10', that seems arbitrary as customer 2 has no 2nd balance record.
5. I purposefully split the logic into several CTEs so I could comment on each step easier, you could definitely perform several steps in the same code block for a more condensed query.